# Gitignore misc.xml and *.iml with Android Studio 0.8.9

Tags: android, android-studio, gitignore

Can I just ignore into the gitignore the *.iml and misc.xml files inside and Android Studio project?

Where can I find an official gitignore for Android Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I just ignore into the gitignore the *.iml and misc.xml files inside and Android Studio project?

Sure, why not? Android Studio is generally very good at importing Android Gradle projects and recreating the IDEA files, so anyone else working on the project shouldn't have a problem checking out the project and getting it to build.

There isn't an "official" .gitignore. What you choose to ignore is generally left up to you.

Most of Android Studio's configuration files (the .iml files and everything under /.idea) are basic project configuration that you don't need to worry about. If you are making changes such as manually ignoring folders in the IDE or disabling certain IDE code quality checks, you might want to check those respective files in so you have a consistent project setup across your team. For the vast majority of projects, you do not need those files at all.

Some teams also prefer ignoring all IDE-generated files and folders to keep the project IDE-agnostic. Whether you want to do that or you want to enforce a particular IDE on your team is another decision left up to you.

When you create a new Android Studio project, it will automatically generate a .gitignore for you. The default .gitignore as of October 2014 looks like this:

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
.idea/
app/app.iml
*.iml
```

Android Studio also currently generates a second .gitignore in your Android module's directory containing just `/build`.

Comment: I think the original question is also trying to get at whether those files are of relevance to other members of a project or are more related to your local IDE preferences related to a particular project. Your answer addresses what a .gitignore is for, which I do not believe is particularly helpful for this question.

Comment: How come even with your suggestions .iml files continue to be added to version control local changes? How to ignore specific files maybe.

Comment: If you already have it checked into git, you need to remove it before it will be ignored. Beyond that, it is hard to answer without knowing more about your specific situation, so you should ask a new question with more detail.

Comment: to be simple, if you already ignored ".idea/", it is safe to remove "/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries". That same to "app/app.iml", because you already set "*.iml"

Comment: @portfoliobuilder use "git update-index --assume-unchanged <path-to-file>" to remove the files directly after adding .gitignore

Comment: [This post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206933675--idea-misc-xml-question) says misc.xml should be included in version control.